# Position:Fixed messing up UI while loading in mobile

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-position

I am building one single website for both mobile and desktop.I am using the Fixed position for the header to satisfy the navigation requirement(like scroll spy).It is working fine in desktop version.When i try to browse the same in mobile version,since i made the min-width:850px; the content is not showing up properly in the mobile.Because of the fixed position i cannot able to drag to the header also.

I have found that http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads this MS website follow the same, when i minimize the website i am having the same problem.But when i load that page in mobile , the webpage loads in complete zom out mode,but mine zoom in and fits the page to the mobile browser.I wounder there must be some trick to make the page zoom out completely, so that while loading in the mobile it wont break.

If anyone have any idea, pls share. I have made a simple fidle to demonstrate my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/rg46D/6/

```
   <div style="position: fixed; height: 70px; background-color: lightcoral;width:100%;min-width:950px">
```

P.S: i cant change the minimum width of the page.

Comment: are you using jQuery-Mobile framework?

Comment: no, i am sorry wrongly tagged

Comment: try using [viewport `meta` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: EDIT - Moved to an answer

Comment: @Omar:No luck, that didnot helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice learning for me.I found the problem by myself.If you are not following the responsive design and having some of fixed width , never use this tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I have removed it , it is working just like desktop in mobile..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the min-width and place some padding on the navigation container instead:

```
<div class="header" style="position: fixed; background-color: lightcoral;width:100%;">
        <a href="#Home" style="padding-left:60px">Home</a>
        <a href="#Links" style="padding-left:60px">Links</a>
        <a href="#about" style="padding-left:60px">About</a>
        <a href="#Home" style="padding-left:60px">Link1</a>
        <a href="#Links" style="padding-left:60px">Link2</a>
        <a href="#about" style="padding-left:60px">LInk3</a>
    </div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
.header {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rg46D/7/

Comment: Thanks, but the moves the header to next line. because in desktopmode i shouldnt want to move the navigation to the second line.

Comment: Where would you expect it to go? It can't stay where it is and not be accessible. Average screen width is now higher than 1000px so putting the `min-width: 950px` isn't always going to be a good thing

Comment: cant we shrink the page on page load like when you load this page as mobile user agent http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads  it loads perfect even though it has a width of : 980px.i want to zoom out the page just like that.

Comment: Most people would go with responsive design these days rather than hoping the mobile browser will zoom in and out to parts of the page. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design